# Execute function without sending 'self' to it

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is that possible to define a function without referencing to `self` this way?

```
def myfunc(var_a,var_b)
```

But so that it could also get sender data, like if I defined it like this:

```
def myfunc(self, var_a,var_b)
```

That `self` is always the same so it looks a little redundant here always to run a function this way: `myfunc(self,'data_a','data_b')`. Then I would like to get its data in the function like this `sender.fields`.

**UPDATE:**
Here is some code to understand better what I mean.
The class below is used to show a page based on Jinja2 templates engine for users to sign up.

```
class SignupHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        utils.render_template(self, 'signup.html')
```

And this code below is a `render_template` that I created as wrapper to Jinja2 functions to use it more conveniently in my project:

```
def render_template(response, template_name, vars=dict(), is_string=False):
    template_dirs = [os.path.join(root(), 'templates')]
    logging.info(template_dirs[0])
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(template_dirs))
    try:
        template = env.get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        raise TemplateNotFound(template_name)
    content = template.render(vars)
    if is_string:
        return content
    else:
        response.response.out.write(content)
```

As I use this function `render_template` very often in my project and usually the same way, just with different template files, I wondered if there was a way to get rid of having to call it like I do it now, with **self** as the first argument but still having access to that object.

Comment: What do you mean, "sender data"? The caller is not necessarily the instance.

Comment: It's not clear if you want a static/class method, i.e. don't want an instance at all, or if you want self to be implicit ("self is always the same" sounds like this). Show some code that highlights what you're doing now and what you want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't *need* self, you can use the `staticmethod` decorator to create a method which does not receive the object as its first argument:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(bar, baz, qux):
        pass
```

If you're writing code which deals only with class-global data, by contrast, you can use a class method:

```
class Foo(object):
    global_cache={}
    @classmethod
    def set(cls, key, value):
        cls.global_cache[key] = value
```

If, by contrast, you're writing code which really does need to refer to the object instance -- `self` is part of the language. Part of the Zen of Python is that "Explicit is better than implicit", and the use of `self` is an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

To call a function that exists in a class, but does not need to know anything about itself (hense removing the self argument), you can use the [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

An example of this might be

```
class Person:

  @staticmethod
  def barbar(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # Has no idea of the class or instance in which this was called on.
    pass
```

To call this, you would do something like:

```
Person.barbar("hi","bye","jump")
```

Comment: Note that this has exactly one, pretty weak, advantage over a module-level/"free" function: It's in the classes namespace. If you're just learning Python, you should ignore them because you rarely need them, as opposed to e.g. Java and C# where they're common.

Comment: You could argue that this should just be factored out into a module or whatever, however it is in the classes namespace because it logically belongs there, it isn't some random function.

Comment: Whether it belongs there depends. Yes, there ae legitimate use cases (didn't I say that?). However, there are way more cases where a e.g. a long-time C# user might lean towards a static method that should really be e.g. a classmethod.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write self, that's just convention, but when a method of an object is called it is fed the object as its first argument, so you will have to give it a name. In tight code developed on my phone I've used `s` before, and when interfacing with C++ code I've used `this`, but it's usually best to use `self`

---

### Update0

Oh wait, you're not defining an object method. Maybe your should be, then you run `object.func(*args, **kwargs)` as opposed to `func(object, *args, **kwargs)`. I'd need to see what you're trying to do to know what's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should create your own subclass of `webapp.RequestHandler` and define your  `render_template` method on it:

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def render_template(self, template_name, vars=dict(), is_string=False):
        # Body of render_template, with "request" replaced with "self" ...
```

Then you use it like so, in your views:

```
class SignupHandler(MyRequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.render_template('signup.html')
```